# Screen resolution is not restored after using TeamViewer

Tags: windows-10, teamviewer

Using TeamViewer, when I work on my computer at home from a different location, I always change the screen resolution. When I return home and wake up my computer, the screen resolution used to be restored to my default. Only recently, this is not the case anymore, and I need to restart my computer to accomplish this. Is there another way of doing this, besides going into the Windows settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to have been resolved by itself. This might indicate a Windows issue and not a TeamViewer issue.